# Could NOT find LLVM (missing: LLVM_DIR) on docker-compose run Building Arrow

Tags: macos, cmake, build, llvm, pyarrow

```
-- Could NOT find LLVM (missing: LLVM_DIR)
CMake Error at /opt/_internal/cpython-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find LLVMAlt (missing: LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION CLANG_EXECUTABLE
  LLVM_FOUND LLVM_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/_internal/cpython-3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake_modules/FindLLVMAlt.cmake:71 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/gandiva/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package)
```

I am currently trying to build a lighter wheel version of Apache Arrow for manylinux2014 using the guide in the Arrow repo [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/python/manylinux201x). I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and have installed Docker desktop and have Xcode.

After getting this error, I ran `brew install llvm` and downloaded llvm `10.0.0_3` in `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/`. I then did `export LLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/lib/cmake` as suggested [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/43) but am still getting the exact same error. What could I do here to allow me to run `docker-compose run -e PYTHON_VERSION="3.8" centos-python-manylinux2014` without errors.

Comment: Probably a typo, but you should remove the spaces surrounding the equals sign when setting `LLVM_DIR` : `export LLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/10.0.0_3/lib/cmake`

Comment: yes that is a typo. edited!

Comment: I would wonder who emits the error `-- Could NOT find LLVM (missing: LLVM_DIR)`. Looks like it is some `FindLLVM.cmake` script, which calls `find_package_handle_standard_args` macro with the `LLVM_DIR` parameter. But none script which I have googled have such call. Exactly that script you need to hint about llvm location, and it seems the script doesn't check `LLVM_DIR` when it is set as an environment variable.

Comment: Update: This error only happens when Arrow is built with Gandiva (which relies on LLVM) but that does not resolve the problem

Comment: This is confusing as you tell us that you want to build things in docker for manylinux2014 but then install things with homebrew. On which system are you building this currently? Linux or macOS?

Comment: Yes, I believe I was slightly confused. One problem was that the dockerfile was not configured to install LLVM.